# Como evitar múltiplos downloads do JAR com JNLP?

Tags: java

Eu tenho um aplicativo baseado em JNLP, mas cada vez que o usuário clica no arquivo JNLP, javaws faz download de todos os jar's da minha aplicação mesmo sem nenhuma atualização no lado servidor.

Eu li toda a documentação, o arquivo é assinado com um certificado de confiança da DigiCert.

Usamos a recomendação da oracle, como descreve a documentação:
[Http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update)

Minha grande dúvida está neste lugar da documentação "quando se sabe que uma atualização está disponível antes que o aplicativo seja lançado", como eles sabem que o app precisa ser atualizado, e se o JNLP é o mesmo, eo app no ​​servidor são os Mesmo, por que eles são atualizados.

Estou utilizando também o versionamento conforme o link abaixo

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html.

O servidor é o WildFly 10, minha aplicação JSF roda nele e dentro da pasta webaap tenho uma pasta com o nome jnlp, onde ficam meus jar's e o jnlp.

Segue meu jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="http://www.meudominio.com.br/jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>app-client</title>
        <vendor>AtlanticaSoft</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.meudominio.com.br" />
        <description>Aplicação cliente</description>
        <icon href="icon.png" kind="default" />
    </information>  
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>  
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="512m" java-vm-args="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m" />
        <jar href="lib/app-client.jar" version="1.0" main="true" />
        <jar href="lib/app-client-dependency.jar" version="1.0" />
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="br.com.atlanticasoft.app.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

Obrigado a todos.